# azure mobile services calling sql server stored procedure and get a requestTimeout 15000ms error

Tags: sql-server, node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

I keep getting this error:

{"name":"RequestError","message":"Timeout: Request failed to complete in 15000ms","code":"ETIMEOUT","number":"ETIMEOUT","precedingErrors":[]}

How do I increase the timeout for my request?

I am not sure if this is coming from the sql server database or from the node.js service?

How do I see what is happening with sql server from azure?

I have sql server management studio and visual studio so i can login to my database, but don't see how to increase timeout etc.

Are there any parameters I set in node.js to increase timeout?

I found this:

http://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-node/global.html#dataConfiguration

and presume I have to set something in my query object?

My node.js API that I call, searchService.js

```
var HttpStatus = require('http-status-codes');

module.exports = {
    "post": function (req, res, next) {
        var resultSet = {
            TotalRecords: 0,
            Results: null
        };
        var parameters = [
            { name: 'forumId', value: req.body.forumId },
            { name: 'registrantId', value: req.body.registrantId },
            { name: 'userId', value: req.azureMobile.user.id },
            { name: 'exclusive', value: req.body.exclusive },
            { name: 'type', value: req.body.type },
            { name: 'categoryIds', value: req.body.categoryIds.join(",") },
            { name: 'locationIds', value: req.body.locationIds.join(",") },
            { name: 'unitIds', value: req.body.unitIds.join(",") },
            { name: 'priceIds', value: req.body.priceIds.join(",") },
            { name: 'delimiter', value: "," }
        ];

        console.log("parameters = " + JSON.stringify(parameters));

        var query = {
            sql: "exec SearchServicesStrictTotal @forumId, @registrantId, @userId, @exclusive, @type, @categoryIds, @locationIds, @unitIds, @priceIds, @delimiter",
            parameters: parameters
        };

        req.azureMobile.data.execute(query)
            .then(function(result) {
                console.log("got result " + JSON.stringify(result));

                resultSet.TotalRecords = result[0].Total;
                res.status(HttpStatus.OK).send(resultSet);
            }).catch(function(error){
                console.log("error one " + JSON.stringify(error));
                res.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).send(error);
            });
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you share more about how you connect to SQL backend? What's the connection string or is there any file wall blocking? I think increate timeout might not really help.

Comment: hi forester, yes, well whats happening is that when i update my stored procedure (sp) and compile it through management studio.  I run the app that then calls the node.js api searchServices.js.  Which calls the sp.  Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.  If i make one change in my sp like delcare a variable, then it breaks.  So I am not sure if its the database or the node.js thats causing it.

Comment: my connection string is set on azure mobile services MS_TableConnectionString "Data Source=tcp:eleutherios.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=eleutheriosDB;User ID=<id>;Password=<pwd>

Comment: Is there a way to see what is happening on the sql server side of things?  How do I access sql server log files through the portal?

Comment: I am connecting from the client to the node.js server via mobileServices.Web.js using a statement like this: var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('<azure website url>')

Comment: So the timeout issue occurred intermittently, not always. I've seen in [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlphp/2015/05/11/getting-started-with-node-js-on-microsoft-sql-server-and-azure-sql-database/) that says you need to use the specific version 0.8.9(32bit) of Node.js which is the only stable version supported, you might try it out.

Comment: I opened kudo console in the azure portal and typed node -v.  It told me i am running v4.4.7.  What about the other things that my site relies on especially other modules that require later versions of node?  This doesn't make sense.  Is there any microsoft people ?  Why should i have to go all the way to version 0.8.9?  It doesn't make sense.

Firebase is looking more and more appealing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default for ***request timeout*** is 15000 ms. To increase the timeout for the request you could try to put this to your app.js file.

```
var mobileApp = azureMobileApps({
    homePage: true,
    data: {
        requestTimeout: 60000
    }
});
```

The app.js file will look like this.

```
var express = require('express'),
    azureMobileApps = require('azure-mobile-apps');

var app = express();

var mobileApp = azureMobileApps({
    homePage: true,
    data: {
        requestTimeout: 60000
    }
});

mobileApp.tables.import('./tables');

mobileApp.api.import('./api');

mobileApp.tables.initialize()
    .then(function () {
        app.use(mobileApp);    // Register the Azure Mobile Apps middleware
        app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);   // Listen for requests
    });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I added the property but get a squiggly green line under the argument that says "argument of type '{homePage: boolean; data: { requestTimeout: number; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Configuration'.  Types of property 'data' are incompatible...".  Is it the right property or should it be connectionTimeout of the sqlServerDataConfiguration object or something? Confused.

Comment: Please ignore that.

Comment: Thanks aaron it seems to be working now.  I think the stored procedure (sp) was taking a little longer or for sql to work out an execution plan or something.  Everytime I compiled the sp sql server didn't respond immediately and was taking a little longer.